# Get link value only from the_content()?

Tags: links, the-content

I have my news in posts and I am trying to display the two latest news articles (posts) on my main page. I've got that solved by getting the title using [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) and getting a little bit of the text using [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt).

I want to show a *more...* link that takes you to the post.  However, some of the news articles that I am posting have some text in the post body that's a link, how do I only get the link within the body of a post so that my *more...* link takes your there directly?

For example, sometimes we will link to news articles in PDFs that are on another server.

I'm using the following code.

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=news2011'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php /* the_ID(); */ ?> 
    <?php /* the_date('F Y'); */ ?>
    <ol class="news">
        <strong><p><?php the_title()?></p></strong>
        <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
    </ol>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scan the content to see whether it contains a link and then parse it to find the `href` attribute. There are many ways to do this, this example uses the built-in kses functionality, [as demonstrated by Otto](http://ottopress.com/2010/wp-quickie-kses/):

```
$post_link = get_the_permalink();
if ( preg_match('/<a (.+?)>/', get_the_content(), $match) ) {
    $link = array();
    foreach ( wp_kses_hair($match[1], array('http')) as $attr) {
        $link[$attr['name']] = $attr['value'];
    }
    $post_link = $link['href'];
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, sorry for the _really_ late reply.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution is perfect but it will only take http links. By using the below code it will take both http and https links.

```
$post_link = get_the_permalink();
if ( preg_match('/<a (.+?)>/', get_the_content(), $match) ) {
    $link = array();
    foreach ( wp_kses_hair($match[1], array('https','http')) as $attr) {
        $link[$attr['name']] = $attr['value'];
    }
    $post_link = $link['href'];
}
```