# Get first URL from post content

Tags: php, functions, loop, post-formats

Basically all I want to do is if the post format is "link" rather than link to the post from the blog index, link to the link pasted within the post content.

In my index.php I have:

```
<h3>
 <a href="<?php get_post_format() == 'link' ? some_function_here() : the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h3>
```

Obviously some_function_here() is not real. I am sure I saw a function on the Wordpress codex that does this (pulls the first link from a post) but I can not find it now.

Answer (score 1):

[I think this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13448/get-link-value-only-from-the-content) might put you in the right direction.

In case that link is broken, here's the answer as provided by [Jon Fabry](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/8/jan-fabry) in that thread.

```
$post_link = get_the_permalink();
if ( preg_match('/<a (.+?)>/', get_the_content(), $match) ) {
    $link = array();
    foreach ( wp_kses_hair($match[1], array('http')) as $attr) {
        $link[$attr['name']] = $attr['value'];
    }
    $post_link = $link['href'];
}
```

This would grab EACH link provided within the content. You can add a counter or a true false condition to just snag the first one.

So the final code would be something like

```
$post_link = get_the_permalink();
$first = true;
        if ( preg_match('/<a (.+?)>/', get_the_content(), $match) ) {
                $link = array();
                foreach ( wp_kses_hair($match[1], array('http')) as $attr) {
                if ( $first ) {
                        $link[$attr['name']] = $attr['value'];
                        $first = false;

                } else {
                // ignore it
                }
        }
        $post_link = $link['href'];
}
```